# concatenate date column from DB with report output name for scheduled report?(No bursting)

Tags: job-scheduling, obiee, bi-publisher

How can we concatenate a column with report output name.this column value is different from "sysdate" or "systime".no bursting should be implemented.Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: can you show an example of what you want/are asking?

Comment: let report name is ABC,and date column value is 28-4-2015.So report output name should come like ABC-28-4-2015.